# Выборка уникальных записей T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть исходная таблица

```
ID| Param  
2 | 1  
2 | 3  
2 | 4  
2 | 8 
5 | 1  
5 | 2   
5 | 3
7 | 4  
7 | 8
8 | 4   
9 | 3
```

Нужно сделать выборку результирующим набором которой будет:

```
2 | 1  
5 | 2   
7 | 4   
8 | NULL   
9 | 3
```

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

**Обновление**

Результат может быть `1-3 | 2-1| 3-2` или `1-2 | 2-3| 3-1`, порядок выдачи Param не важен, должны быть уникальные и ИД и параметр.

Приведу другой пример исходящих данных `1|4; 1|7 ;2|4 ;2|5 ; 3|6;` результатом выборки должна быть таблица `1|4 ;2|5 ;3|6`.

ИД добжно быть столько, сколько их есть уникальных и к ней должен быть приписан один уникальный столбец.

Comment: Какие то они у вас чересчур уникальные. Они как бы изначально уже уникальные у вас. Почему на выходе нужен именно 2-2, а не 2-1 скажем ? Или вам нужны именно строки с совпадающими id-Param ?

Comment: Уникальные id и параметр это тупо `select distict id,param from table`. Просто они у вас во входных данных уже уникальны. а выходных часть param отсутствуют

Comment: Я кажется начал понимать что вы хотите ... как бы два набора id и параметры, как бы не связанные, но расположенные в соседних колонках. правда не ясно, что делать если разных id больше чем разных параметров или наоборот

Comment: с таким наблром входных данных я не вижу логики формирования ответа. исправьте свой вопрос, пожалуйста, чтобы данные были актуальными

Comment: @Миша стало еще непонятнее, куда делся id=8 из начальной выборки

Comment: объясните подробней, почему в результате у вас нет 8 | 4  ?

Comment: Потому, что Param 4 уже есть в выборке в паре с ИД = 7

Comment: у вас дерево значений? param - это parentID ?

Comment: @Миша А теперь хотелось бы понимать _зачем_ вам такое понадобилось. я пока не представляю как подойти к решению этого вопроса, т.е. может оно и решаемо одним запросом, но он будет очень жуткий. А вероятность того, что вы хотите чего то совсем иного очень высока ...

Comment: @Миша и какова сортировка изначальных данных, потому как если при ваших данных поменять сортировку то на выходе уже не окажется какого нибудь другого ID

Comment: Я попробую объяснить. Есть n комнат и m предметов, которые нужно поместить в эти комнаты. комнаты все разные(ID) и предметов каждого по 1 штуке(Param). Нужно разместить в каждую комнату по 1 предмету. Cортировка ID asc

Comment: А вот тут есть 8-ка.

9 | 3
8 | 4
7 | 8
5 | 2
2 | 1

 Задача сформулирована неоднозначно.

Comment: Я поправил результирующий набор, надеюсь так стало понятнее. Спасибо

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (id int, [param] int)

insert into @t (id, param)
values (1,1),(1,2), (1, 3), (2,1), (2,2), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3,3)


select t.id, t.param from @t t
where t.id=t.param
group by t.id, t.param
```

группировку по вашим данным делать не олбязательно, конечно, но вдруг у вас есть повторения

Comment: Нет, этот запрос не подходит. Возможно я запутал входными данными... Уловие t.id=t.param не подходит, ID могут существенно отличаться от Param.

Comment: отредактируйте исходный ваш вопрос с учётом актуальных исходных данных

Comment: что должно в итоге быть,  если в исходных данных будет дополнительно id=1,param=4?

Comment: Тот же самый результат и должен быть. Не должно быть повторений Param во всех наборах с уникальным ИД

Comment: 1|7 ведь тоже не повторяется, разве не так?

Comment: @Миша Т.е. если на входе три записи: 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 то на выходе должна быть одна, например 1-1 (потому как других уникальных id больше нет, а "лишние" значения параметров мы просто отбрасываем)

Comment: Да, именно так.

Answer (score 1):

В SQL Server есть [Функции среды CLR с табличным значением](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms131103(v=sql.120).aspx), и если нжна сложная выборка/обработка данных, то можно использовать C#.

Ниже реализация метода Map, который возвращает необходимый результат

```
2 1
5 2
7 4
8 NULL
9 3
```

---

Пример использования Map

```
var rows = Parse("2|1; 2|3; 2|4; 2|8; 5|1; 5|2; 5|3; 7|4; 7|8; 8|4; 9|3");
foreach (var row in Map(rows)) 
   Console.WriteLine(row.Id + " " + (row.Param == -1 ? "NULL" : "" + row.Param));
```

---

Реализация Map

```
class Row { public int Id; public int Param; }

IEnumerable<Row> Map(IEnumerable<Row> rows) {
    var used = new HashSet<int>();
    foreach (var g in rows.GroupBy(i => i.Id)) {
        var p = g.FirstOrDefault(v => !used.Contains(v.Param));
        if (p != null) used.Add(p.Param);
        yield return new Row() { Id = g.Key, Param = (p != null ? p.Param : -1) };
    }
}
```

---

Реализация Parse -- требуется только для примера

```
IEnumerable<Row> Parse(string str) {
    return str.Split(';').Select(s => {
        var t = s.Split('|');
        return new Row {
            Id = int.Parse(t[0].Trim()),
            Param = int.Parse(t[1].Trim())
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: 2 колонки ТС хочет , а здесь одна

Answer (score 1):

```
with Q as
 (
  select id,parm,1 F,
         Cast('/'+Cast(id as varchar)+'.'+Cast(parm as varchar)+'/' as varchar(max)) R
    from test1 where id=(select min(id) from test1)
 union all
  select B.id,B.parm,B.F+1 F,
         Cast(B.R+Cast(B.id as varchar)+'.'+Cast(B.parm as varchar)+'/' as varchar(max)) R
    from (
    select A.id,A.parm, Cast( dense_rank() over(order by A.id) as int) N,Q.R,Q.F
      from test1 A, Q where A.id>Q.id and Q.R not like '%.'+Cast(A.parm as varchar)+'/%'
    ) B where B.N=1
 )
select distinct id,parm from
(
select id,parm,max(replicate('0',5-len(Cast(F as varchar)))+Cast(F as varchar)+R) over () R
  from Q
) A
where R like '%/'+Cast(id as varchar)+'.'+Cast(parm as varchar)+'/%'
```

Только [этот запрос](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b6ec3/2/0) не совсем точно выполняет вашу задачу. Он ее выполняет лучше, чем вы хотели. Т.е. он находит наилучшее распределение уникальных parm среди уникальных ID и для вашего примера получается следующее решение:

```
2   1
5   2
7   8
8   4
9   3
```

А вообще такие задачи лучше решать не на SQL. Ибо SQL не предназначен для таких запросов. В крайнем случае это можно решать хранимыми процедурами, с использованием временных таблиц (Либо массивов, которых в T-SQL нет).

Comment: _"такие задачи лучше решать не на SQL и не в базе, а на клиенте."_  -- в SQL Server есть CLR

Comment: Я прочитал, что вы написали, только смысла решать на CLR в базе, что бы потом отдать это на клиента который и так может это посчитать не вижу. Это я говорю с учетом того, что судя по комментариям это для какой то игры, ибо распределение предметов по комнатам вообще непонятно что делает в SQL

Comment: _"только смысла решать на CLR в базе, что бы потом отдать это на клиента который и так может это посчитать не вижу."_ -- если данных много, а клиент - это смартфон.

Comment: И смартфон устанавливает непосредственное соединение с MS SQL ... Ну может и так конечно, хотя соединение с неким как минимум бакэндом, а может даже фронтэндом мне кажется более вероятным

Comment: _"И смартфон устанавливает непосредственное соединение с MS SQL"_ -- в SQL Server есть поддержка веб-сервисов. но наверное это редко используют.  _"с неким как минимум бакэндом,"_ -- ок. но так SQL Server не очень нужен, если все данные на клиенте,  закешированы, и все делается в коде на C#